# PDF merger code results in corrupted file?

Tags: python, pdf

Brand new to python, I have written a code using the PdfMerger from PyPDF2 to merge multiple PDFs in VS code while producing a new merged PDF. This worked, however my resulting PDF is corrupted and unviewable. I sent the code to my colleague who ran the code on his linux machine, and the resulting merged PDF was viewable for him. Is there anything I should change with my code that could fix this?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger
import os

merger = PdfMerger()

path_to_files = r'pdfs/'

for root, dir, file_names in os.walk(path_to_files):
    print(file_names)
    for file_name in file_names:
        full_path = path_to_files + file_name
        new_file = merger.append(full_path)

merger.write("merged_all_pages.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.